# Filter on multiple indexed columns slow Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, performance, optimization, indexing

I am having a table with 2M rows and running a query using 5 columns all of them indexed. Still the query execution time is more

Query:

```
SELECT cmp_domain as domain, slug, cmp_name as company_name, prod_categories, prod_sub_categories, cmp_web_traff_rank 
FROM prospects_v5.commercepedia 
WHERE
    country='United States of America' 
    AND 'Shopify' =ANY (technologies) 
    AND is_live = true 
    OR 'General Merchandise' =ANY(prod_categories)  
order by cmp_web_traff_rank 
LIMIT 10
OFFSET 30000;
```

Below is the explain Plan:

```
"  ->  Gather Merge  (cost=394508.12..401111.22 rows=56594 width=109) (actual time=14538.165..14557.052 rows=30010 loops=1)"
"        Workers Planned: 2"
"        Workers Launched: 2"
"        ->  Sort  (cost=393508.10..393578.84 rows=28297 width=109) (actual time=14520.435..14523.376 rows=10175 loops=3)"
"              Sort Key: cmp_web_traff_rank"
"              Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 3896kB"
"              Worker 0:  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 4056kB"
"              Worker 1:  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 4096kB"
"              ->  Parallel Seq Scan on commercepedia  (cost=0.00..391415.77 rows=28297 width=109) (actual time=6.726..14439.953 rows=32042 loops=3)"
"                    Filter: (((country = 'United States of America'::text) AND ('Shopify'::text = ANY (technologies)) AND is_live) OR ('General Merchandise'::text = ANY (prod_categories)))"
"                    Rows Removed by Filter: 459792"
"Planning Time: 0.326 ms"
"Execution Time: 14559.593 ms"
```

I have created btree index on country ,is_live and cmp_web_traff_rank and gin index on technologies and prod_categories.

When I use AND condition for all columns below is the explain plan

```
"  ->  Gather Merge  (cost=269444.76..269511.27 rows=570 width=109) (actual time=10780.530..10785.326 rows=1672 loops=1)"
"        Workers Planned: 2"
"        Workers Launched: 2"
"        ->  Sort  (cost=268444.74..268445.45 rows=285 width=109) (actual time=10762.765..10762.862 rows=557 loops=3)"
"              Sort Key: cmp_web_traff_rank"
"              Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 125kB"
"              Worker 0:  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 133kB"
"              Worker 1:  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 124kB"
"              ->  Parallel Bitmap Heap Scan on commercepedia  (cost=19489.58..268433.12 rows=285 width=109) (actual time=318.652..10759.284 rows=557 loops=3)"
"                    Recheck Cond: (country = 'United States of America'::text)"
"                    Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 18486"
"                    Filter: (is_live AND ('Shopify'::text = ANY (technologies)) AND ('General Merchandise'::text = ANY (prod_categories)))"
"                    Rows Removed by Filter: 80120"
"                    Heap Blocks: exact=18391 lossy=10838"
"                    ->  BitmapAnd  (cost=19489.58..19489.58 rows=107598 width=0) (actual time=259.181..259.183 rows=0 loops=1)"
"                          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_is_live  (cost=0.00..4944.53 rows=267214 width=0) (actual time=52.584..52.584 rows=271711 loops=1)"
"                                Index Cond: (is_live = true)"
"                          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_country  (cost=0.00..14544.45 rows=594137 width=0) (actual time=199.594..199.594 rows=593938 loops=1)"
"                                Index Cond: (country = 'United States of America'::text)"
"Planning Time: 0.243 ms"
"Execution Time: 10790.385 ms"
```

Is there any way I can improve the query performance further.

Comment: What is the total number of rows in the table that match the conditions? About 30,000, is it?

Comment: Are you 100% sure about the ... AND ... AND ... OR ... construction? Is that the correct logic? Rows Removed by Filter is for both query plans pretty high, looks like an issue as well. Can you filter in the indexes?

Comment: I have changed the filter to all AND  conditions. Still in the attached explain plan you can see the performance is slow

Comment: @Atchaya did you implement my suggestions? If they haven't made any difference can you share new explain analyze buffers output?

Comment: @boran Thanks for your inputs. Yes it worked. Do I have to set the work_mem everytime I run the query?

Comment: @Atchaya you can set it in postgresql.conf file. The default value 4MB is too low for most workloads 32-64MB should be fine. However if you want to set it to much bigger value it is better to set it per session,  you would not want to give each query too much work_mem.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some low hanging fruits:

try increasing work_mem to eliminate lossy bitmap heap scan. You can inspect it and set it with:

```
SHOW work_mem;
SET work_mem = xx;
```

If applicable drop index on `is_live` and create other indices as partial conditioned on `is_live`.

The plan does not use your gin indices right now. Try using operators that uses gin index like

```
'Shopify' =ANY (technologies)  ->  technologies  @> '{Shopify}' ;
```

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. Yes it worked. But do I have to set the work_mem everytime I run the query?